# Creating Deck of Cards- possible setting values more efficiently?

Tags: java, object

im trying to create a deck of cards. Suites are standard. Description Ace to king. but the value is 1 to 10 with queen king and jack being 10 as well. I am having trouble thinking of a way to initialize the proper values more efficiently.

my card class uses symbolic constants stating that the field will only be initialized if and when the value is between 1- 10. Though when I have tried to set values greater than 10. the value is still changed. I know I am missing something.

These are my constants and setter method for class card.

```
public static final int MIN = 1;
public static final int MAX = 10;

/**
 * @param used to set the value field as an int
 */
public void setValue(int value){

    if(value >= MIN && value <= MAX){

        this.suit = suit;
    } else {
        
        System.out.print("Please input a suit");
    
    }
}
```

This is my suite and description array

```
public static final String[] SUITS = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"};

public static final String[] DESCRIPTIONS = 
    {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five",
        "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine","Ten", 
        "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
```

This is my crude method in Deck class though I named my deck card

```
/**
 * loads deck with cards
 */
public void loadDeck(){
   int value = 1;
   int counter= 0;
   for(int suits = 0; suits < 4; suits++){
        
       for(int description = 0; description < 13; description++){

            int index = 0;
            
            card[index] = new Card (DESCRIPTIONS[description], SUITS[suits], value);
           
            System.out.println(card[index].getSuit() + card[index].getDescription()
                + card[index].getValue());

            index++;

            if(value == 10) {
                
                value--;
                counter++;
                if(counter == 4) {
                    value = 0;
                    counter = 0;
                }

            }
            value++;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you need to set value for cards from `Ace` to `Ten` as 1..10 _and_ `Jack`, `Queen`, `King` should be assigned value = 0 for any suit?

Comment: Ace to Ten should be 1..10 and King Queen King should be all 10

Comment: So this should work fine: `new Card (DESCRIPTIONS[description], SUITS[suits], description < 10 ? description + 1 : 0);`, then `value` and `counter` become redundant.

Comment: ahhhh nicee, ternary. Do you know why my cards arent being saved to the array? for example if I run a .showAllCards method. only the last card/only card shows up. clubs  king 10

Comment: I figured it out cus my index was always set at 0

Comment: Yeah that was a nice bug - you create a card, print it and expect that it exists in the array :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the card score a different attribute from your card face.

Card

- face (Ace..King)
- color (spade, hearts, diamonds, clubs)

This allows you to render your cards normally.
Your score function could also simply return a value <= 10, calculating the score from the face value.

```
int getScore() {
    return Math.max( face, 10);
}
```